# How to know my add-in is open in Excel task-pane Office 365?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, add-in

I am creating an Office 365 plugin for Excel using Angular. I use Office-JS library to interact with Excel. My plugin appears in the Excel task-pane.

I want to know that my add-in is open/close in task-pane via code, I want to know as I need to solve some issue related to this in my add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately our API doesn't provide the event for Taskpane open/close. which is a known feature gap.

So would you please provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563 and upvote for this feature. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi Ray ,need to ask -can we add matrix in word js ?

Comment: I would suggest you could create feature ask in Word JS and upvote this feature as well.